# Find first empty slot in an array in Godot 3.2.3

Tags: arrays, loops, inventory, godot

I have an inventory array that I want to find the first empty slot in the said array and put the Resource the player picks up into that slot. I'm a little familiar already with C programming and am pretty sure that a for loop would work nicely, I just can't seem to get it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.find](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html#class-array-method-find) to find the index of first element of your array that is `null` (assuming you're using `null` to indicate empty inventory slots).

It will return the index of the first empty slot, in which case you'd do `inventory_array[index] = picked_up_item`. Or, if the inventory is full (i.e. there is no `null` element), it will return -1, in which case you should do something reasonable (like not pick the item up).